# Splitting string into columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split

I'm having some difficulty with splitting the following string:

> "greeting1": "hi", "greeting2": "hello", "greeting3": "hey"

...into my desired output as separate columns:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+
| greeting1  | greeting2  | greeting3 | 
+------------+------------+-----------+
|   hi       |  hello     |   hey     |               
+------------+------------+-----------+
```

FYI- I am using SQL Server, the maximum number of greetings is five, and I know of a STRING_SPLIT function that I could use but I don't really know how to use it- also considering the amount of quotation marks and colons in my string. Any feedback or suggestions would be super helpful! Thank you. :)

Comment: Don't store such values to begin with. This is a major bug. In this case, splitting isn't enough, you actually need to handle name and value pairs. This looks a bit like JSON so you could surround this string with `{ ..}` and use `OPENJSON` to read this string as a JSON object.

Comment: And what if there are more than three greetings?

Comment: MSDN documentation is quite clear. See: [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: That does rows, not columns, @MaciejLos , and delimited strings, rather than (slightly) malformed JSON.

Comment: @Larnu, agree, but it's quite easy to convert rows into columns ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2016+, you may parse the input text as JSON using `OPENJSON()` and explicit schema (the `WITH` clause). If the maximun number of greetings is five, you need to use the appropriate columns definitions:

```
DECLARE @text varchar(1000) = '"greeting1": "hi", "greeting2": "hello", "greeting3": "hey"'

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('{', @text, '}')) WITH (
   greeting1 varchar(1000) '$.greeting1',
   greeting2 varchar(1000) '$.greeting2',
   greeting3 varchar(1000) '$.greeting3',
   greeting4 varchar(1000) '$.greeting4',
   greeting5 varchar(1000) '$.greeting5'
)
```

Result:

```
greeting1 greeting2 greeting3 greeting4 greeting5
-------------------------------------------------
hi        hello     hey
```

Comment: In before the OP says "But I need to do this dynamically." 

Comment: Thank you very much!